# Xcode any 3D engine constant slow memory increase

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, memory, scenekit

Edit: I thought maybe it was just SceneKit but then I made a new Xcode project for OpenGL and Metal and both of these engines have the same problem as SceneKit, memory slowly increases. Can someone please tell me whats up with that? Is it normal? Why?

I recently started working with scene kit, every time I animate any node with SCNAction.repeatForever or update rotation or position with the render loop there is slow gradual increase in memory shown in the debug session. This even occurs with the base project that apple provides, its a simple as a jet rotating however the memory increases continuously about .1 mb per 5-10 seconds. Ive let it run for over half an hour and it just keeps increasing. Ive also tried stopping the animation and the memory does not get freed. Ive tried using multiple devices and turned `scnView.showsStatistics = false`

The code that causes the problem from what I can see is:

```
self.cubeNode.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 0.01, z: 0, duration: 1.0/60.0)))
```

or

```
func renderer(_ aRenderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        rot += 0.01
        self.cubeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(rot, 0, 0)
    }
```

Has anyone else noticed this issue? Can I do anything about it? Any ideas, suggestions, or opinions are greatly appreciated!

EDIT: 
I noticed:
If I do not use Actions instead go the route of an update function.
As soon as I have this line in the code:

```
self.scnView.isPlaying = true
```

Even if I don't change anything in the scene and even before I add any other code like setting the delegate or adding the update function (func renderer) the memory goes up.

I will be looking into this problem further and will post an update if I get it working without memory increase, I also submitted a bug report to apple about their base project automatically increasing memory soon as you build and run it.

EDIT:
If go the route of using an OverlaySKScene and using the update function there to update the position of the cube, the memory goes up, thats without setting

```
self.scnView.isPlaying = true
```

Even after the cube is out of the camera the memory still goes up.

Conclusion:
Anytime a node is updated in the scene memory goes up.

What to do?

Comment: What happens if you increase the duration of the action to 1 second, or 10 seconds? Why do you need a new action every 1/60 of a second? Do you see any changes over time using the Memory Graph Inspector?

Comment: Actions are, generally speaking, a shortcut to making modular animations in  a very primitive sense and manner. I don't think they're well thought out, nor conceived in their first instance. The origin of the actions idea is something borrowed from cocos2D. And they're really not well suited to being used for a frame or three's duration. Try overriding the update() function to do this kind of per-frame animation. https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate

Comment: I tried using the action at every 60 seconds and the memory still goes up the same. I moved the code `code rot += 0.01
        self.cubeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3Make(rot, 0, 0) ` to a sprite kit update and the memory still goes up.

Comment: 22 December 2019, Problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently apple is aware of this and they will fix it in 10.2

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/64295

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/67384

EDIT:
Apple has fixed this in the latest Xcode build.

Comment: 22 December 2019 Problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I experienced exactly the same and was able to nail it down to exactly the same conclusion as you: 
**SCNAction.repeatForever() "eats" the memory.**
May be file a bug to Apple ?

Also the other SCNActions seem to have issues... (I have to investigate this)
I do not yet have a solution for this. I tried to replace SCNActions with  CABasicAnimation() - which resulted in exactly the same problem (rotation eating memory):

```
let rot = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "eulerAngles.z")
rot.byValue = r
rot.duration = time
rot.repeatCount = .infinity
self.addAnimation(rot, forKey: "rotendless")
```

Comment: It is not just the actions that are causing the problem because if I don't use them and update the cube via an update function be it rotation or position the memory goes up. Its like if the scene is visually updated at all the memory goes. I don't have this problem when I move a sprite around the scene in spritekit. Just seems like scene kit has this problem.